# Android (Java) SharedPrefs data sync via Firebase - make one request instead of a bunch

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find the best way to sync the data from SharedPrefs, but there are no ideas.

I'm trying to use own way and it actually works. I have few files in Prefs: "Sets" file that contains some data and info about the names of another Prefs. This way I firstly should put data from "Sets" and then put data from his child elements.

This way we have too many requests to Firebase. But Firebase has a monthly limit of free requests. This way it is important to make one big request instead of a bunch of requests.

```
SharedPreferences Sets = getSharedPreferences("Sets", MODE_PRIVATE);

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Map<String, Object> mainSPRowData = (Map<String, Object>) Sets.getAll();

Map<String, Object> mainSP = new HashMap<>();
mainSP.put("ACTIVE_USER", mainSPRowData.get("ACTIVE_USER"));
mainSP.put("USERS_COUNT", mainSPRowData.get("USERS_COUNT"));


DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).collection("Sets").document("MainSet");

documentReference.set(mainSP);
for (String row : (HashSet<String>)mainSPRowData.get("USERS")) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(row, MODE_PRIVATE);
    documentReference.getParent().document(row).set(sp);
}
```

How can we?

My Firestore schema:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- users (collections)
    |     |
    |     --- email: mymail@google.com(document)
    |            | 
    |            --- Sets(colletion)
    |                  |
    |                  --- MainSet
    |                        |
    |                        ---ACTIVE_USER: "3"
    |                        ---USERS_COUNT: "21"
    |                  --- user1
    |                  --- user2
    |                  ...
    |                  --- usern
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in this code the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo it produces lots of requests: reading and writing. But it should have only one writing request